# ASP.NET Core with .NET 4.6.2 and VS 2017 RC

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Using Visual Studio 2017 (RC), I am trying to setup a project that uses ASP.NET Core, but with the .NET 4.6.2 library.

This is a supported configuration:

[image: ASP.NET Core with .NET Framework]

Visual Studio will then create a default project; but it doesn't run:

[image: Crash with default VS 2017 template]

This is without changing a single line in the project: the VC2017 template just does not work.

I tried the following:
- Different versions of the .NET framework
- x86, x64, AnyCPU
- Clear the NuGet cache
- 'Repair' options on Visual Studio's installer.

My understanding is that the error is a x86/x64 mismatch. But since I didn't change a single file from the template, there has to be something else wrong.
Installing ASP.NET Core on .NET Core works perfectly, so the problem is limited to using the regular .NET framework.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have installed both versions of the .NET Core runtime? (x86 and x64)? iirc the last one installed will set itself as default in the path environment variable

Comment: My installation of VS 2017 RC also misbehaved, lot of errors in default project without doing anything, no compiling. What fixed that was run as administrator, voila...everything worked. I have no idea what's the problem but administrator privilege does the trick for me. Try.

Comment: As an update, since I did this: None of the ASP project (non core) run on this machine anymore! They all have x86/x64 conflicts where it tells me that DLLs are in a bad format. VS2017/Core is far from ready I think.

Comment: I just uninstalled .NET core (which was the correct x64 for my project) and tried also to run as admin, but nothing changed.

Comment: btw, just to conclude this: the only solution I had was to reinstall VS from scratch...

Comment: I just learned the root of the problem and I want to share it: when installing .NET core, the VS setting to run IIS Express in 64bit is reset. That's what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem too. But I just found the solution.
In ".csproj"  I change some things:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
<!--<RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>-->
<RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier></PropertyGroup>
```

And I [enable the 64-bit version of IIS Express](https://ppolyzos.com/2015/12/01/enable-x64-bit-version-of-iis-express/).

Comment: that doesn’t fix it here

Answer (score 0):

I had problems like these when I restored stuff to a new laptop.

I mindlessly I copied files from my old profile directory to a directory with the same name, but that isn’t a profile directory on the new machine.

A part of this process involved a cloud backup service that my wife bought for me but that I never actually set up right. That also copied files to new locations without my paying attention to what was happening.

I still don’t know (yet) exactly how the machine keeps track of which versions of frameworks and tools to use in the various application directories, but I can report what I did that finally allowed me to create new .NET Core apps on the new machine.

I deleted everything in this directory that was older than today.

%USERPROFILE%.nuget\packages

Again, pretty mindless. I don’t know, (yet) if all that was necessary. Maybe just deleting one or two of the files/directories would have worked. Regardless, I was very happy to see that I could create and develop .NET Core apps on my new machine.